# ggplot2 geom_step() produces curve that "starts to far left"

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shiny

I am currently trying to produce some graphs using `geom_step()`. Here is my code:

```r
ggplot(usage_data,aes(x = to_regulate_up)) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  geom_step(aes(y = 1 - after_stat(y)), stat = "ecdf", linewidth=0.5, color="black") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  labs(title = "1 - CDF of used aFRR capacity", x="Used capacity", y="Probability")
```

When i the output of this plot into an RShiny Application via ggplotly i get what i expected:

correct plot
[image]

When trying to save the plot to a svg (`ggsave(file="/tmp/curve2.svg", plot=plot, width=8, height=4)` or when plotting the same thing in RStudio i however get the following result:

incorrect plot
[image]

As in the curve starts at 100% and then drops down, which is not what i want.

I already tried setting different `xlim` parameters to make the curve start more to the right but still got the same result.

Thanks for any insight to what might be the problem.

P.S. i dont really think it has anything to do with exporting the plot to a svg, because in the RStudio Plot pane it also looks the same.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `pad = F`in the geom_step()

```
df <- data.frame(a = runif(200))

ggplot(df,aes(x = a)) + geom_step(aes(y = 1 - after_stat(y)), stat = "ecdf", pad = T) # default value adds point at Inf and -Inf
ggplot(df,aes(x = a)) + geom_step(aes(y = 1 - after_stat(y)), stat = "ecdf", pad = F)
```

[image]

[image]

see `?stat_ecdf`:

`pad:   If TRUE, pad the ecdf with additional points (-Inf, 0) and (Inf, 1)`